# How to 2D visualize points on a 3D plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am trying to 2-D plot a set of points that lie on the same 3-D plane.

I give an example to be more clear: I have a plane, which normal is $N=[1, 1, 2]$, and I have three point which lie on the plane:

$p_1 = [0, 0, 0]$
$p_2 = [2.5, 1.5, -2.0]$
$p_3 = [2.33, 0.33, -1.33]$

How can I visualize these points on a 2-D flat space? Using plotting softwares I am able to put the 3-D coordinates and to exactly look at $N$ using an orthographic camera, but this is cheating :D

Comment: Use Rodrigues rotation formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula around the intersection line from the given plane and the $z=0$ plane.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the normal vector. Three points define a plane. To project these points to two dimensions we can do the following.

Construct two vectors whose tails are at a common point. In your example we can construct $$\vec u=2.5\hat i+1.5\hat j -2\hat k$$ and $$\vec v=2.33\hat i+0.33\hat j-1.33\hat k$$

Compute the lengths of those vectors to get $\lvert\vec u\rvert$ and $\lvert\vec v\rvert$.

Take the dot product and use the calculated magnitudes to get the angle $\theta$ between the two vectors, i.e. $$\vec u\cdot\vec v=\lvert\vec u\rvert\lvert\vec v\rvert\cos{\theta}$$

Our plane will consist of the span of those two vectors in the plane. For convenience, we can place $\vec u$ along the $x$ axis and use the angle between the two vectors to get $$\vec u'=\lvert\vec u\rvert\hat i$$ and
$$\vec v'=\lvert\vec v\rvert(\cos{\theta})\hat i+\lvert\vec v\rvert(\sin{\theta})\hat j$$

Comment: Wonderful, thank you a lot!